# GC generation 3 appearing in windbg

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I've a dump file of a process I'm running (trying to find a memory leak)

One thing I've noticed is that when I dump the bigger objects via !do windbg tells me that they are GC generation 3 ??

All of these are byte arrays so when I look at all the byte arrays in the dump I can see GC generations 0, 1, 2 & 3.

Could someone explain whats going on here as I thought there was only 3 generations of GC.

```
> 0:000> !do 0x0000000011b47450 
Name: System.Byte[]
MethodTable: 000007fef7d2e798
EEClass: 000007fef7932670
Size: 131096(0x20018) bytes
GC Generation: 3
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 131072, Type Byte
Element Type: System.Byte
Fields:
None
```

Comment: There is separate storage for large objects in terms of GC generations.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, what value is `GC.MaxGeneration` ?

Comment: And is there a correlation with size? Objects over 80 kB go on the LOH

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .NET Framework has a fourth heap ("generation") specifically for large objects, called -- appropriately enough -- the Large Object Heap.  Objects larger than 85,000 bytes are allocated onto that heap.

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163833.aspx

> One undocumented feature of the "!dh" command is that you can easily look at the large object heap as well. In looking at a lot of output, I noticed some values listed as coming from Generation 3. Because the .NET garbage collector, at least according to everything I read, only has the three generations (0, 1, and 2), I was a little confused. Thinking it may be the large object heap, I manually dumped the large object heap and compared values. Sure enough, that's what I saw. To see the objects in the large object heap, use 3 as the generation like this: "!dh –stat –gen 3".

Comment: One reason for this is it would be costly and sometimes impossible to move these large objects around in memory.  So .NET doesn't bother with all of the compaction and promoting through generations as with smaller objects.

Comment: This is the first that I've heard of the LOH being considered generation 3.  It's clearly plausible and it even seems like the most likely explanation, but are there any references supporting this?

Comment: Given that the OP noticed it when dumping "bigger objects," it seemed a reasonable assumption.  However, I did manage to find a specific reference here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163833.aspx

Comment: @ColeCampbell : please quote and link to that inside the answer.

Comment: Cole - looks like you've got it in a nutshell. All the objects which are shown as gen 3 are LOH objects. I've added the output from !do above.